# Division algorithm for polynomials discrete maths

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

> **Problem:** State the *division algorithm for polynomials*. Using this result, show that, if the polynomial $f(x)$ has a root $a$, then the linear polynomial $x-a$ divides $f(x)$.

I’m incredibly stuck on this problem from a sample exam. I don’t know what the question wants me to do or even how to answer it. The only thing I know is what the division algorithm is.

Comment: By the division algorithm, $f(x)=g(x)(x-a)+r(x)$ so if $f(a)=0$ then $r(x)=?$

Comment: Ahhhh  Would I rearrange for r(x)?

Comment: Set $x=a$ in $f(x)=g(x)(x-a)+r(x)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So that means g(x) and (x-a) would cancel out and we'd be left with f(a)=r(a) and if f(a)=0 it means r(a)=0 and so theres no remainder?

Comment: Yes, there's no remainder, so $(x-a) $ divides $f(x)$, QED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the division algorithm, there exist unique polynomials $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $f(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r(x)$, and $\deg r(x) < \deg (x-1)$.

From the last inequality, note that $\deg(x-1) = 1$ and so $\deg(r(x))=0$, so $r(x) \equiv r$ is a constant. Hence,
$$
f(x) = q(x)(x-a) + r.
$$

What happens when $a$ is the root of $f$? Can you evaluate this last equation and finish the problem?

Comment: if a is the root of f then f(a)=0 and x-a is a factor?

Comment: so this means f(x) = r?

Comment: @user639649 can you prove that if $a$ is a root of $f(x)$, then $r = 0$? That would indeed imply $x-a$ is a factor of $f(x)$ as desired

Comment: @user639649 more correctly, $f(a) = r$, but if $a$ is the root of $f$...

Comment: if a is the root of f then that means there is no reminder..?

Comment: @user639649 more precisely, you can find the value of $r$ exactly (what does *no remainder* mean about $r$). Since $r$ is a *constant*, it does not depend on $x$, so what does $f(x)$ look like?

Comment: f(x)=r ? so r=0 and thus x=a because f(a)=q(a)(a-a) + r  sorry if i keep getting it wrong

Comment: Basically, when you divide some polynomial by x-a, the remainder must be one degree less than in the polynomial x-a, the polynomial you divide by. To figure out the value of r in your case, you evaluate $f(a) = 0 = p(a)q(a) + r$, so r is zero. You have no remainder.